# Running a command several times on a unix window on a PC with minor change each time

Tags: json, unix

I have found a way to get my heart data from fitbit by using this command on a unix window on my PC:

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer longtokenofcharacters" https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/heart/date/2018-01-01/1d/1min/time/00:00/23:59.json > mydata20180101.json
```

and it works perfectly giving me a file with data every minute of one day.

What I would like to do is get more data without having to enter this command and manually edit the date each time I do it.  Can I create something which runs this command many times (e.g. 31 times) changing two digits in the command and the filename from 01 to 31 each time?  i.e. once it has run I have 31 files, one for each day of January.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not a code writing service - you are expected to put some effort into writing some code, and we'll help you make it work. The next challenge is to choose your development language. You could do this using bash, but that's a painful route, and  you would be better using (IMO) Javascript as there are plenty of npm modules to help you. Other languages like Perl and Python would work well too

Comment: Mikkel, thanks for the very swift response.  Given I am starting from no knowledge of bash or Javascript or Perl or Python, which would you recommend as easiest to learn to give this a go?  I have managed to make something work in Visual Basic once, but that's the only language (except excel macro language) that I know.

Comment: Javascript is a good place to start, as it is the language of the web, and can also be used on the server too. On SO the js topic is very popular

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'll have a look at learning enough javascript to solve my problem.